# Power BI Error while applying query changes

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I import data from SQL server into Power BI through Import Query. The data loaded fine to the power query, but when I apply changes I got the following error:

> Apply query changes
>   Transaction
>   Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Invalid operation. The connection is closed.

the power query doesn't have any transformation steps it just retrieving the data

SQL Code:

`SELECT * FROM CPEInventory.dbo.Transitions`

Answer (score 0):

SQL Code is not required for this scenario - I would just use the Navigation UI to select the database, schema and table or view.